# Design Pattern to Implement Timeouts

Tags: design-patterns

I'm trying to design operations timeout logic for my service. Each operation interacts (sync & async) with multiple downstream services. The purpose is to be able to kill the operation after certain time regardless of the state.

Is there any design pattern which can be leveraged in the solution?

Comment: This sound like observer pattern if you really want to use design patterns for this. It will signal the observers itself. For async, you would just want to post a message to it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to access your downstream services and then use some kind of event-driven approach to handle success/timeouts.

```java
public interface ICallback {

    public void onSuccess(DsObject object);

    public void onTimeout();
}
```

The way you access your downstream services may look like this:

```java
public class DownstreamConnector implements Callable<DsObject> {

    @Override
    public DsObject call() {
        // Invoke your downstream services here
        return ...
    }
}
```

You can then wrap the callable around a `Future<>` to invoke your downstream services and check for timeout.

```java
final ICallback callback = new MyCallbackHandler();
final DownstreamConnector connector = new DownstreamConnector()

ExecutorService executor = ...
Future<DsObject> future = executor.submit(connector);

try {
    DsObject result = future.get(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILISECONDS);

    // Operation completed
    callback.onSuccess(result);
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    logger.error("Operation timed out", ex);
    future.cancel(true);

    // Timed out
    callback.onTimeout();
}
```

---

> Just a comment: `future.cancel(true);` does **not** stop the running underlying task, it just sets the interrupted flag to true for the running thread. It is your code that is responsible to check this flag and throw `InterruptedException` if it is true.

---

- [Ref. 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)
- [Ref. 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))
- [Ref. 3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)